# Work with Amazon S3 API in C

Tags: c, amazon-s3, libcurl

If there someone who worked with Amazon S3 API in C? I can't manage to sign my REST request proper. Can someone share his successful experience in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never tried it, but a quick Google turned up [the libs3 C library API for Amazon S3](http://libs3.ischo.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html). That might make things easier, so you don't have to deal with raw HTTP requests via `curl`.

Comment: thanks, for some reason when I googles I found other libs, that wasn't suitable, but not this one. So I'm going to try this one..